# PowerCenter Designer issue with COBOL VSAM file

Tags: sql-server-2008, informatica-powercenter, vsam

I'm working in PowerCenter Designer on a Cobol Mainframe VSAM sourcefile and need to know what values in `Prec` and `Scale` should I use to get a `PIC S9(9)V99 COMP-3`...
A coworker mentioned Informatica recognizes it like `PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3`, and so I had to defined the field with `Prec 11` - `Scale 2`, and I did that, but once data gets loaded in Stage table in SQL, then some fields show strange symbols for some columns, and other columns show expected values.

I also tried adding an Expression transformation for dividing by 100 the resulting value gotten from the Normalizer, but it didn't work as expected either.

Do you have any idea about how could it be handled?

Answer (score 0):

The '`pic s9(9)V99 COMP-3`' is interpreted as follows:

s -- signed.
9(9) nine number digits.
V the implied decimal point.
99 -- two numeric digits 
comp-3 -- packed decimal.

In informatica this would be '`prec 11 scale 2`'.
Cannot remember how you tell Power Center its packed decimal
but I know you can.

Packed Decimal: two decimal digits in each byte with a special sign character in the last nibble.
So +123456 is stored as hexadecimal  `'0123456C'.`
( +123.456 would be stored as exactly the same hex string -- you just have to know what the scale you are expecting!)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a comp-3 field means that the value is compressed, so if you open with a text editor will show you those strange characters not the specific number
you can saw those values with the extension PowerExchange